# Why can't I change state using React devtools?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I want to be able to change state in a React app using React devtools, for example, setting `loaded` to `false` instead of `true`. I am not able to edit the value. This is true both on localhost and on the live web app. Why do some boolean values have a checkbox and others don't?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the component containing the state you wish to alter, there is no state in the component selected in the screenshot. If the state property does not have a checkbox you can select the value, input a new value, then hit enter or click away and it will update.